# Django Sorting by multiple fields without respect to object

Tags: python, django

So I have a model that has a generic foreign key to three other models lets call them A, B, C.

I want to have them ordered by date.Currently the method for sorting I am using is like

`statuses = statuses.order_by('A__datetime', 'B__datetime', 'C__datetime')`

however this sorts datetimes for A, then datetimes for B, then for C.
So overall they are not in order just the chunks are.

Is there anyway to have them all sorted by date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show model of your relations? It is not clear right now which way relations are defined.

Comment: I think you can't do that using order_by, you will need to find a python way to di it without using Django ORM

Comment: As @GwynBleidD said, you should first post your `models.py`

Comment: A B C are models that you are using as if they were keywords for sorting, IDK about that, try getting the 3 sorted results u get and merge them in to one :)